# how to animate shape transformations with react

Tags: html, css, reactjs, web-deployment

I want to make an animation that takes a box like in picture 1 and splits it into boxes like in picture 2.

[image: 1][image: 2]

I tried a few basic libraries (like animate.css) but none offered animations that were advanced enough to accomplish something like this. How can I accomplish something like that, should I use a library or is it uncomplicated enough to do in vanilla js?

Comment: how should the animation go from (1) to (2)?

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript. Take the element and make a function to change borders of specific elements
I would suggest to use the functions start as per need. I am just writing the script and body. sorry if it is not good. i am new to this community.
for eg -

```
<script>

function ani()
{var x = document.getElementById("whatever").style.border = "none";
 var y = document.getElementsByClassName("need");
 var n= y.length;

 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {y[i].style.border="solid";}}


 function nani()
{var x = document.getElementById("whatever").style.border = "solid";
 var y = document.getElementsByClassName("need");
 var n= y.length;

 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {y[i].style.border="none";}}

</script>
<body>
 <ul id="whatever" onmouseenter="ani()" onmouseleave="nani()"> chacha
  <li class="need">1</li>
   <li class="need">2</li>
   <li class="need">30</li>
 </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what kind of animation do you need? And what are you planning to do with those blocks before animation and after animation.

If you only need boxes then canvas or SVG may be an answer:

- [Canvas API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API)
- [enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG)

But I am guessing that you need to animate actual DOM elements. In that case approach to the problem need to be fallowing. You need to have stable DOM tree and than you need to change DOM elements' style in gradual way.

There is three ways to do that:

1. Using pure JavaScript and updating `domElem.style.*` [attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) at least 25 times per second yourself.
2. Using [CSS3 Animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations)
3. Or using [CSS3 transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions)

I all adding example of transitions. I am using vanilla js to trigger animation (by changing `domElem.className`). But it can easily be done using React or whatever.

Example:

```js
function main() {
  setTimeout(startAnimation, 500);
}

function startAnimation() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    var split = document.getElementById("split-" + i);
    split.className = "state-end";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
}

#main {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 20px auto 40px auto;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

#split-0,
#split-1,
#rect-0,
#rect-1,
#rect-2 {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #333;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#rect-0 {
  height: 50px;
}

#rect-1 {
  height: 50px;
}

#rect-2 {
  height: 240px;
}

#split-0,
#split-1 {
  margin-left: -1px;
  margin-right: -1px;
  width: 402px;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;

  transition: opacity 0.4s, height 1.0s ease-in, margin 1.0s ease-out;
}

#split-0.state-init,
#split-1.state-init {
  height: 1px;
  margin-top: 29px;
  opacity: 0;
}

#split-0.state-end,
#split-1.state-end {
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body onload="main()">
    <div id="main">
      <div id="rect-0" class="state-init"></div>
      <div id="split-0" class="state-init"></div>
      <div id="rect-1" class="state-init"></div>
      <div id="split-1" class="state-init"></div>
      <div id="rect-2" class="state-init"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```